# ASP NET CORE MVC-Application and "Double-Logout"

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, visual-studio-2019

I've a problem with "double-Logouts" of my ASP NET CORE 3.1 MVC App.
The problem is:
- run the app
- login
- open a second browser-window of the same site
- click logout in one of the Windows
- now the problem...click logout in the second window: a white page appears, url is set to "https://localhost:44305/Identity/Account/Logout?returnUrl=%2F" and nothing happens…

The error occures at a new project, setup with the default VS 2019 template!

Anyone an idea?

BR Marco

Comment: If I understand, your problem is how to access logout browser session from another browser, you can't do this

Comment: if you can provide your logout Code, we can try to fix this

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here within your question.

Answer (score 0):

No, not another browser, only another tab of the same browser!

I've no logout-Code, it is inside of the "default asp net core template"! If you build a new Asp Net Core MVC App, you will have the same behaviour!

The only thing I have is the "code" of the logout-form (generated by VS2019):

```
<form class="form-inline" asp-area="Identity" asp-page="/Account/Logout" asp-route-returnUrl="@Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { area = "" })">
    <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link text-dark">Logout</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

> click logout in the second window: a white page appears, url is set to "https://localhost:44305/Identity/Account/Logout?returnUrl=%2F" and nothing happens

I can reproduce same issue, and if we check the request in browser network tab, we can find it returns **400** status code , like below.

[image]

Based on my test and research, the issue seems be caused by [antiforgery token validation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-3.1#antiforgery-options) while you click logout button in second browser tab.

If you want to skip antiforgery token validation, you can try to [replace the default 
code of Logout PageModel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#create-full-identity-ui-source) and apply `IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` to it, like below.

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
public class LogoutModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly SignInManager<IdentityUser> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LogoutModel> _logger;

    public LogoutModel(SignInManager<IdentityUser> signInManager, ILogger<LogoutModel> logger)
    {
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void OnGet()
    {
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPost(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        await _signInManager.SignOutAsync();
        _logger.LogInformation("User logged out.");
        if (returnUrl != null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }
        else
        {
            return RedirectToPage();
        }
    }
}
```

Test Result

[image]